# How to get Status by SAMLResponse using xpath

Tags: javascript, xpath

When I use XPath below with SAMLResponse,

```
.//*[local-name(.)='Status']/*[local-name(.)='StatusCode']
```

I get a result.

```
<saml2p:StatusCode xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
```

But my final goal is getting whether status is 'Success' or not.
How can I get 'Success' string by '<....2.0:status:Success" /> using Xpath?
I can get 'Success' using split method in js. like string.split("status:"). But I wonder if I can get that result by Xpath. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Since you're very likely using XPath version 1.0, the closest thing you can get is the attribute value `'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success'`. After that, you would need to use JS to split it, which means whatever you're doing right now (show it?) is probably already fine.

Comment: If this qualifier `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:` is always the same, you can use [`substring-after()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring-after) function like: `substring-after(.//*[local-name(.)='Status']/*[local-name(.)='StatusCode']/@Value, 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:')`